# How can I make a job editable only via the Jenkinsfile and make GUI readonly?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I prevent GUI from overriding the Jenkinsfile configration? Is there to lock all the config options in the GUI except the ones required to specify the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Enable the authorization strategy and lock everything to an openldap role that no one is assigned to

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli : not necessarily the answer the OP was looking for, but it's probably the best one. You should write it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can only do what the Authorization granularity allows (Authorization is separate to Authentication - [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529712/598141) for more on that). Authorization is under `{JENKINS_URL}/securityRealm/`.

To restrict access, you must configure Authorization to one of:

- Matrix-based security
- Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy
- Role-Based Strategy

You require at least [Matrix Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/) plugin. For more information, review Jenkins Security on [the site](https://www.jenkins.io/security/), or [the book](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/).

If you enable basic Matrix authorization, it comes with two roles: Anonymous Users and Authenticated Users. It's probably better to use the "[Role-Based Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/)" for any sizeable user base, but the premise is the same.

The basic Matrix authorization has the following capabilities for a "Job".

- Build
- Cancel
- **Configure**
- Create
- Delete
- Discover
- Move
- Read
- Workspace

First, you want to add a user (yourself)  or group and give them Overall Administer and/or all permissions so as not to lock yourself out. You then want to remove "Job:Configure" and "Overall:Adminsiter" for regular users (plus other permissions as needed; read the docs referenced). Now Users cannot edit the job.

If you want to provide the User a choice of Jenkinsfile to run the job with, then you can add [Parameterized Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/) plugin and you can provide a list of Jenkinsfile parameters they can choose from at runtime. Extensions also exist (search [plugins for parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search/?labels=parameter) for options) for nicer UI constraints, like [Filesystem List Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin/), where it chooses from filesystem (basing that on plugin description, not actual use).

If using inputted Jenkinsfile (as opposed to checked-in to the repo), you can also look at using [Config File Provider](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/) to restrict to centralized, manged config files.